# Baker's Percentages for Baked Doughnuts?

Tags: quickbread, doughnuts, baker-percentage

I recently purchased an electric doughnut maker and am about to embark on a baked doughnut spree.  Having consulted the few recipes included with the machine along with some online options, I have noticed considerable variation in the recommended batter composition.  I was wondering if anyone has seen or established a reliable set of baker's percentages for baked doughnuts they could share.

The two most consistent ratios among the recipes I've seen are:

Flour - 100% (naturally)

Sugar - 50%

After that, all bets seem to be off:

Fat (some combination of butter/oil) - 20%-35%

Egg - 25%-35%

Liquid (some combination of milk/buttermilk/sour cream/yogurt) - 70%-80%

I'm not concerned with the salt, spice, and leavening amounts - I'm more interested in the variations of the ingredients that contribute significant weight to the recipes.

Aside from the King Arthur and Epicurious recipes I found, no other recipes were able to supply weights so the percentages I supplied above are mostly estimates based on the assumption of a 5 oz. cup of flour (which I know is not universally applicable). My guess is that, as with most quickbreads, the recipe is probably robust with the amounts supplied more likely to correspond to simple volumetric measures and whole egg inclusion rather than weights (I'm pretty sure that the King Arthur recipe is based on volumes and the weighted versions you can query online are just conversions to weight based on their own established system - for example, in King Arthur's world, a cup of flour always weighs 4.25 oz.).

Anyway, can anybody offer me a reliable set of baker's percentages or weights for baked doughnuts that you have tested personally?  I like to have these things worked out before I try new things.

Comment: Given the lack of answers -- I would just note that after you asked your question a couple weeks ago, I did spend some time looking up doughnut formulas in at least a half dozen professional baking/pastry books (which are most likely to give baker's percentages).  While I came up with quite a few formulas for standard fried doughnuts, I couldn't find a single baked doughnut recipe/formula in those sources.  I'm not saying what you look for doesn't exist, but if the pros do this by weight, I assume they'd use a standard cake batter or quickbread formula/recipe.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input.  I also checked a LOT of books and came to the conclusion that any doughnuts that are non-yeasted, non-cake, or non-fried are probably just considered "un-professional" - I prefer fried doughnuts too but they aren't practical on a small scale.  I jumped-in anyway with 100% flour, 50% sugar, 80% buttermilk/sour cream, 25% egg, and 25% butter/oil with some baking powder, salt, and vanilla.  Tasted great, but I always love to hear from people with more experience - hence my query.  Thanks again.

Comment: Places I've worked that made baked donuts generally used either a muffin or poundcake recipe. The only thing that really differentiates baked donuts from any other small baked good is the shape, so any other quickbread recipe you like should work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big doughnut fan. I've watched a lot of Unique Sweets episodes and it seems that the shops with the best doughnuts usually use a standard **brioche recipe** as it is rich in flavour, but also yeast risen... Thus it gives you the perfect texture and flacvour.

I wouldn't use ANY bread recipe that it measured in volume. Weight is far more accurate, especially for something with sensitive chemistry like bread.

Comment: Just the "measure by weight" alone deserves an upvote! Welcome to the site!

Comment: A brioche recipe might work for fried doughnuts, but if you used it for a baked doughnut, you'd end up with .... brioche.  I would expect you'd have to go with something more cake-y for baking.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ratio I am currently using after consulting the internet for recipes, a few experiments and comparing to my normal bread ratio.

**Ratio**

Bread flour (10) : Full cream milk + Egg (6) : Butter (1)

Weigh your eggs first, then weigh the milk to get the correct ratio.
E.g for 300g flour, 180g milk and egg (120g milk, 1 60g egg), 30g butter.

For 300g of bread flour, I use 2 tbsp of sugar and 2 tbsp of yeast.

**Notes**

The recipes I've found seem to vary a lot. Some use almost double the amount of butter, all seem to understate the amount of yeast needed. Some will use whole eggs, others 1 whole egg, then yolks only for 500g of flour.

Also, I have only tried this with just bread flour. I think a combination of bread and plain would give a better result.